# Select XML tags when number of child tags are not fixed from a large xml file

Tags: perl, unix

**Select XML tags when number of child tags are not fixed from a large xml file**

I have a large XML file:

```
<root>
    <A>xyz</A>
    <B>xyz</B>
    <C>xyz</C>
    <info>
        <data>...<data>
    </info>
    <info>
        <data>...<data>
        <another_random_tag>....</another_random_tag>
    </info>
    .
    .thousands of info tag
</root>
```

Now i want to cut 10,000 info tags and save them in new file part_1.xml (smaller size files)

Please suggest How to perform that task in **Unix** or **perl**.

Comment: @mpapec i want to select pairs of 10k and store them into part_1, part_2 files etc.

Comment: @Bharat check out [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.20/lib/XML/Simple.pm) easy to use. Or other XML modules on cpan.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/release/XML-Twig)'s `xml_split` for this. The `-g` option does just this:

```
-g <nb>  groups <nb> elements in a single file.
         The content of each file is enclosed in a new element 
         ("xml_split::root"), so it's well-formed XML.
```

You can install XML::Twig either through CPAN (or `cpanm`) or through your package manager, on Debian-based distributions it is in `xml-twig-tools`